# Simplify a polyline/polygon using a threshold on maximum number of vertices in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, generalization

The various simplification functions in PostGIS (e.g. [ST_Simplify](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Simplify.html)) uses a `tolerance` parameter for the maximum allowable deviation of the generalized shape from the original. My question is:

*Is there an effective way to generalize a geometry so that in the end the number of vertices in the output does not exceed a given number?*

(This is with latest PostGIS 2.5 on PostgreSQL 11)

Comment: You can compute the needed value by doing a range-bounded iterative evaluation, splitting half the difference between high and low (binary search), but that's going to be computationally expensive.

Comment: The [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) is iterative, so it's possible to rewrite it so it "stops" when the number of items in `PointList[]` (or whatever) is less than the threshold number.